# How to remove slice element using append?

Tags: go, slice

I want to remove some struct element from pointer array

Here is my struct

```
type User struct{
    userName string
    userId   int
}
```

And I m trying to remove item like that.

```
allUser []*User
------------
------------
------------
func RemoveUser(deletedUser *User) {
    for ii := 0; ii < len(allUser); ii++ {
        if allUser[ii] == deletedUser {
            allUser = append(allUser[:ii], allUser[ii+1:])
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error.
**cannot use allUser[ii+1:] (type []*User as type *User in append**
What's my fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)
>
> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be
>   passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument
>   is followed by `...`.

---

`append` is a variadic function. You need to add `...` to append a slice.

```
allUser = append(allUser[:ii], allUser[ii+1:]...)
```